# Measure keyboard height in iOS using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Is there a way to calculate the height of the keyboard in iOS using javascript/jquery? Or, what I'm really after, the actual viewport height?

I have seen answers that use Swift. I'm not looking for a native code answer.

I have seen answers that use innerHeight. This works with Android, but not iOS (at least not iOS 11). Activating the keyboard fires $(window).resize() in Android, but not in iOS.

Is it just not possible?

Comment: is this true on all browsers on iOS? the keyboard on safari looks like the browser overlays it and doesn't actually effect the rendered page

Comment: resize doesn't fire on Safari when the keyboard opens and height doesn't change.